# Show that for every ring R, condition FBC implies the condition ACC

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question:
[image]

A Part of Solution that I couldn't understand:
[image]

Could you help me understand this solution(especially red lines)?

I think this solution has some error or is incomplete in red lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $B_N=\{b_1,\cdots,b_n\}$ is a basis for $N=\bigcup N_i$ we must have $b_j\in N$ for each $1\le j\le n$ and so must have $b_j\in N_{i_j}$ for some $i_j\in\{1,2,\cdots\}$ for each $1\le j\le n$. As $\{i_1,\cdots,i_n\}$ is a finite set, it has some maximum $r$. Thus $b_j\in N_{i_j}\subseteq N_r$, that is $b_j\in N_r$, for each $1\le j\le n$. Thus $B_n\subset N_r$.

Now $N_r\subseteq \bigcup N_i=N$, that is $N_r\subseteq N$. As $B_N$ was defined to be a basis for $N$, we have that $N$ is the intersection of all ideals containing $B_N$. We found that $N_r$ is an ideal containing $B_N$, so $N_r$ is one of the ideals in this intersection, so $N\subseteq N_r$. As both inclusions $N_r\subseteq N$ and $N\subseteq N_r$ hold, we must have equality $N=N_r$. Further $N_r\subseteq N_{r+k}\subseteq N\subseteq N_r$ shows $N_r=N_{r+k}$ for all $k\ge1$, so we must have $N_r=N_{r+1}=N_{r+2}=\cdots$. Thus we have proved $\rm FBC\implies ACC$.